# Wordpress pre_get_posts hook doesn't work on Wordpress "page" post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress "page" (post type), with slug `"/mypage"`. On the page (using template `page-mypage.php`) I'm trying to show a custom list of posts, so I thought I'd tap into the `"pre_get_posts"` filter to do that. Inside the template `page-mypage.php` I do something like the following to try and filter the output of the Main Loop:

```
function getuserfavs($query){
  if ($query->is_main_query()){
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        $query->set('post__in', array(130, 128));
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'getuserfavs');
```

That doesn't work, however, and all I get when viewing `"/mypage"` is a 404 page not found template. The Main loop if I look into it isn't altered either. Can anyone explain why this is so? Am I missing something in terms of how `'pre_get_posts'` should be used?

Thanks,

Comment: first try to run static template page in wordpress .

Comment: and we dnt add_action direct in template page ,it has to be done in functions.php

Comment: I tried adding it in functions.php, same result.